# Postgres enums conversion with manually created Record objects

Tags: jooq

We are using jooq with vert.x in a blend where jooq is building queries and the DB calls themselves are executed using vertx postgres client. The legacy system uses jooq 3.11.12 and now we are bumping it to 3.15.5. And this is where we hit the following backwards incompatible behavior.
We have an enum defined in DB:

```
CREATE TYPE model.days_of_week_enum AS ENUM (
'Sunday',
'Monday',
'Tuesday',
'Wednesday',
'Thursday',
'Friday',
'Saturday');
```

and a table column defined as an array of these enums:

```
...ALTER COLUMN days_of_week
  TYPE model.days_of_week_enum[]
    USING days_of_week::model.days_of_week_enum[]
```

Jooq autogenerates the enum class and the table record as expected and all seems fine.
When we read the query response from vertx client the array of enums arrive as an array of Strings, e.g.

```
"Monday", "Sunday"
```

We manually create a Record object and fill in the value that arrived from vertx (as an array of strings)

```
R record = dslContext.newRecord(table);
record.set(fieldDefinedAsOurEnumArray, valueFromVertxAsStringArray);
```

Till here all works ok. But later we are retrieving the values of this field from the Record object using

```
res = (T) Convert.convert(val, field.getConverter());
```

Jooq defines the converter of the field as **IdentityConverter [ [Lcom.xyz.jooq.model.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum; ]**
but with 3.11.12 the method flow continues to:

```
public static final <U> U convert(Object from, Converter<?, ? extends U> converter) throws DataTypeException {
    return convert0(from, converter);
  }

  private static final <T, U> U convert0(Object from, Converter<T, ? extends U> converter) throws DataTypeException {
    Convert.ConvertAll<T> all = new Convert.ConvertAll(converter.fromType());
    return converter.from(all.from(from));
  }
```

which ends up in doing the right conversion, while with 3.15.5 it ends up calling

```
public static final <U> U convert(Object from, Converter<?, ? extends U> converter) throws DataTypeException {
    return converter instanceof IdentityConverter ? from : convert0(from, converter);
  }
```

returning the array of strings as is, which causes a casting error in the Record's getter

```
 public DaysOfWeekEnum[] getDaysOfWeek() {
        return (DaysOfWeekEnum[]) get(4);// get retrieves String[]!
    }
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?
TIA

Comment: There might have been a regression in this area at some point, but I'm not aware of the issue persisting. Since you upgraded, why not upgrade to the latest version? What's the point of upgrading to an old version? Also, rather than posting your analysis of the bug, can you post the code you wrote (including code generation configuration and your actual query code)? Otherwise, it's not easy to try to reproduce anything.